# Const guard for the dynamic data inside class

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I have class with the following so simple struct:

```
class bmp{
    int w;
    int h;
    uchar* data;
}
```

if a function was declared as follow:

```
double do_someting(const bmp& image);
```

it is not allowed to edit `image.h` or `image.w` or the address of `image.data`. However, it is OK to edit the data of `image.data`..

The question :
Is there a way when designing a class to relate the status of the object (e.g `const`) with the state of specific attribute. So, the data of `image.data` will be safe too?

Comment: Make `data` private with a non-const setter?

Comment: It is old but may I know about the down-votes.. really why?

Comment: The problem with downvotes is that if downvoters don't leave a comment and the reason isn't obvious, the OP doesn't know why their question is downvoted nor what they can do to improve it. And they won't even be notified that you posted this comment. I'd suggest you not to pay much attention to them and move on, there's really not much you can do about it.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of solutions:

1. Use `std::vector<uchar> data` (or `std::array` etc.). It will allow to call only `const` methods on `data`, so it will work as expected.
2. Provide own `getData()` and make `data` private. Overload `getData` for const objects (`uchar* getData(); const uchar* getData() const;`)

Answer (score 1):

```
uchar* mutable data;
//     ^^^^^^^
```

Now, `data` may be modified even when its parent object is being accessed in a `const` context.

Be careful with this. It can be confusing.